# Cannot change password policy

Tags: windows-server-2008, password-policy

I am logged in as the administrator in my Windows Server 2008 computer which is a domain controller. The password policies in local security policy are grey and I cannot change them. Do I have to change the policies for the entire domain to work? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. You can change the password policy via Group policy management.

Answer (score 0):

Beat me to it- but more info here. The default domain policy applied to all computers so if you change it in here, it applies to everything.

http://adminvault.co.uk/?p=50